# Prometheus : how do i sum by with 2 different metrics

Tags: prometheus

I have 2 different metrics : 
metric_a with a field type
metric_b with a field type (same one)

I'm trying to summarise a and b, of the same type.
If type exists only on metric_a and not on metric_b - it should return metric_b's result.
I've tried a lot of options on prometheus:

`sum by (type)(metric_a{job=~"provision-dev"}) or vector(0) + sum by(type)(metric_b{job=~"provision-dev"}) or vector(0)` : returns only the values from metric_a, and doesn't calculate metric_b's results.

`sum by (type)(metric_a{job=~"provision-dev"}) + sum by(type)(metric_b{job=~"provision-dev"})` : returns only the values from metric_b, and doesn't calculate metric_a's results.

`sum by (cluster_id)(provision_scale_out_failures{job=~"provision-dev"} + provision_scale_out_success{job=~"provision-dev"})` : well this isn't even a right query

Basically here's an example of a success :

metric_a :

- type = type_1, sum = 5
- type = type_2, sum = 2

metric_b :

- type = type_1, sum = 4
- type = type_3, sum = 3

result of the query :

- type = type_1, sum = 9
- type = type_2, sum = 2
- type = type_3, sum = 3

Answer (score 16):

This is the expected behavior when using a [binary operator](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#binary-operators): both side must have a matching label set to be taken into account.

If you want to be able to aggregate both side and get the single one, you first must get the [union](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#logical-set-binary-operators)  of different metrics using the `__name__` label:

```
 sum by(__name__,type)(metric_a{job=~"provision-dev"}) or on(__name__) sum by(__name__,type)(metric_b{job=~"provision-dev"})
```

You can cascade the [aggregation operator](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#aggregation-operators):

```
sum by (type) (sum by (__name__,type)(metric_a{job=~"provision-dev"}) or on(__name__) sum by(__name__,type)(metric_b{job=~"provision-dev"}))
```

Finally, you can also compact everything into:

```
sum by (type) ({__name__=~"metric_a|metric_b",job=~"provision-dev"})
```

Comment: This works great, but I have a question, do you know how to add a Range operation to the sum? I tried `sum by(type) (idelta({__name__=~"metric_a|metric_b", name=~"my_thing"}[5m]))` but I get an `execution: vector cannot contain metrics with the same labelset` error.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68944000/how-to-avoid-vector-cannot-contain-metrics-with-the-same-labelset-error-when-p

Answer (score 9):

The following PromQL query should sum `metric_a` and `metric_b` by `type`:

```
(sum(metric_a) by (type) + sum(metric_b) by (type))
or
(sum(metric_a) by (type) unless sum(metric_b) by (type))
or
(sum(metric_b) by (type) unless sum(metric_a) by (type))
```

How it works:

- The `sum(metric_a) by (type) + sum(metric_b) by (type)` sums time series with matching `type` label values on both sides of `+` according to [matching rules](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#vector-matching)
- The `sum(metric_a) by (type) unless sum(metric_b) by (type)` returns `sum(metric_a) by (type)` results for `type` label values missing in `sum(metric_b) by (type)`. See [docs about `unless` operator](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#logical-set-binary-operators).
- The `sum(metric_b) by (type) unless sum(metric_a) by (type)` returns `sum(metric_a) by (type)` results for `type` label values missing in `sum(metric_a) by (type)`.

Then results from these three queries are joined with [`or` operator](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#logical-set-binary-operators).

This query is equivalent to the query proposed by Michael: `sum({__name__=~"metric_a|metric_b"}) by (type)` .

P.S. This query can be simplified further when using [MetricsQL](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html):

```
sum(metric_a, metric_b) by (type)
```

This query works, since [sum()](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#sum) function in MetricsQL accepts and sums arbitrary number of arguments.

Comment: Thank you! This form saved me (vs the __name__ one), since I could apply rate to the metrics within the sum this way too. With the __name__ form, prometheus was not very happy.