# Adding two metrics together with a different number of series each

Tags: prometheus, promql

I have two custom metrics:

api_success, api_failure

api_success has a label for "endpoint", and api_failure has a label for "endpoint" and a label for "error_code"

I'm having difficulty writing a query that will give us the total number of requests made per endpoint, by adding these metrics together.

The obvious answer is something like this:

```
sum by (endpoint) (rate(api_success[5m])) + sum by (endpoint) (rate(api_failure[5m]))
```

however, this doesn't actually work. In some cases, an endpoint could have no failures, so prometheus is unable to match the vector from the left side to the right side, and the endpoint simply doesn't show up as a series at all. I have read this page: https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#vector-matching front and back looking for a solution to coerce the right side to have all of the series that the left side does, and use zeroes for all missing series.

This seems like such a basic use case, I can't believe I haven't found an answer.

Comment: I found the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59631025/prometheus-how-do-i-sum-by-with-2-different-metrics?rq=1 

Will close as duplicate